# Why is any lumped parameter system modelled with an ODE?

Tags: control-system

I'm studying Control Theory and the book jumps from a input-output representation of the system to a ODE model. Initially, the book derives that any causal system can be represented as:

\$y(t) = g(x(t),u(t),t)\$

Where x(t) is the state and u(t) is the input. Right after that, it defines a lumped parameter system as one where the state is a R^n vector and just assumes that:

\$ \dot{x} = f(x(t),u(t),t) \$

Does anybody have any idea as to why this is true?

Comment: Does that dot over the x signify time derivative? That would make sense anyway. I think the key to understanding it is that it is causal, and x(t), u(t), t together contain all the information about those causes.

Answer (score 2):

Lumped parameter systems are systems that contain first-order integrators with respect to time (capacitors), first-order differentiators with respect to time (inductors), and multipliers (resistors).

It is immediately trivial to convert a first-order ordinary integral equation into a first-order ordinary differential equation, by differentiating both sides with respect to time.

At that point, the first-order ODE is the natural representation.

The state vector x contains the state variables for each integrator and differentiator.  For a capacitor, the state variable is the voltage across the capacitor.  For an inductor, the state variable is the current through the inductor.

Note that you can "stack" first-order "stages" to get Nth-order systems.

It is really a shame that analog computers have gone out of vogue.  Seeing the elements stack up is a really educational experience.

Comment: But there you used another definition of lumped parameter systems. That's my problem. Even if you didn't restrict yourself to electric circuits, if you assume the systems come from differential equations it's absolutely trivial to see it. The thing is making the connection with the R^n state definition. That any system modelled with ODEs is a lumped parameters system is easy, it's the reciprocal that bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on avoiding the *lumping* of common parameters in a physical system, then you have to accept the alternative - [infinite dimensional systems](http://www.emis.de/monographs/Chueshov/book.pdf). You *can* do this, and it can get you a bit closer to actual system behavior, but at the expense of having to deal with much more complex mathematics that won't necessarily lead you any closer to a control solution, and perhaps not at all. Lumping common types of parameters (distributed capacitance for a single capacitance, for example) provides a mathematical simplification which in many cases is close enough to model system behavior.

Furthermore lumping parameters is a stepping stone towards another point of simplification - the assumption the system is linear. State space systems can be either nonlinear or linear. Linear systems are a whole lot easier to deal with and a well defined system of mathematics has been developed to support control system design around linear systems.